# How do I get the data that is only in one table from a join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
Table A
Column: username
joe
mike

Table B
Column: username
joe
joe
bob
bob
bob
bob
mike
mike
```

I want to see just the usernames that are in Table B but NOT Table A. What is a query that will give me just the username `bob`?

By the way, Table B can have multiple of the same username and Table A cannot, so I am assuming I'll need to use `GROUP BY`?

Comment: `joe` is in A, I'm guessing you meant `bob`

Comment: Yes, I meant `bob`. Fixed

Comment: I updated my code below to give you both cases

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct username 
from b 
where username not in (select username from a)
```

you can also use a join

```
select distinct username 
from b 
left join a on a.username = b.username
where a.username is null
```

Comment: NOT EXISTS is more efficient

Comment: @RobertoNavarro - that totally depends on the platform, not in is best in DB2 and left join is best in SQL Server... not sure about the rest.  Also, the index types and other things can affect it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
SELECT * FROM tableb WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM tablea WHERE tableb.username = tablea.username)
```

Comment: You need to join on username

Comment: Haha, I know how that goes :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

**User in table_a not in b**

SELECT  username FROM table_a a
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_b b
                WHERE b.username = a.username);

**User in table_b not in a**

```
SELECT  username FROM table_b b
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_a a
                WHERE b.username = a.username);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT table2.username
  FROM table1 RIGHT JOIN table2 ON table1.username = table2.username
 WHERE table1.username IS NOT NULL
```